# How to convert static UITableView to dynamic TableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicontainerview

I've got a static TableView that now needs to become a dynamic TableView, because other views need to be placed around the ViewController, and this can not be done using containers in my case.

The question is: how do I efficiently convert the table view from static to dynamic?

I'm aware of having to change the inheritance from UITableView to UIViewController and add the  plus the delegate methods.

But how about all of the Table-Sections: I have 3 sections with 6 types of cell in the static table. Do I really need to subclass UITableViewCell for all of these cell-types and deal with everything manually, or is there a more clever way to do this?

Comment: You just need to change the data source and send a `reloadData` message to the table view. What is the problem?

Comment: @Desdenova as soon as I change the TableViews content Type from static to dynamic in the Storyboard, I loose all sections (apart of the first one) in the TableView

Comment: Why you need to make tableview dynamic now? What's the point? If you are choosing to make your table dynamic, then you have to just hardcode your data in array/dictionary and write boilerplate code to populate tableview. I think static is better option in that case.

Comment: you can resize your static tableview in storyboard, so that you can place other views.

Comment: @brainray ah you are talking about the cells not the tableview itself. I think you should rephrase your question.

Comment: @anum90 resizing id not an option in this case. The TableView is a container-subview that is on top of a push navigation. The TableView  shouldnt fill the screen, the following pushed views should. And: of course I will to the boilerplat dance, I was hoping for something better :-)

Comment: As per your comments below, which container are you using? Do u mean uitableviewcontroller?

Comment: @anum90  no, I'm using a container view (see object libraray). Thats a fine way to get an existing vc (here static tv) into another one (here as a deatail-view)

Answer (score 0):

You really can't just convert between the two. By merely implementing some of the tables delegate methods, like cellForRowAtIndexPath:, you loose your static content. That being said, the table should be dynamic the entire time. This way, you can define logic to determine whether or not it should show the content that you originally added statically, or the new dynamic content.

Additionally, you don't need a view controller to implement the delegate/datasource methods. If you already have a subclass of `UITableView`, that's fine. You can set it as its own delegate/datasource, and implement those methods within the subclass.

And to answer your last question, no there really isn't a better way to do that. I recommend that you create one base class that subclasses `UITableViewCell` that implements everything that the cells will share, and then implement the individual changes in subclasses of this base class. Using multiple cell subclasses in a table view sounds a lot worse then it is.

Comment: Okay, looks that I have to go the way... BTW: I do need a UIViewController for having the possibility to place the TableView whereever I want (using a container doesn't work in this case as described in a comment above)

Comment: Well, doing this from a fully fledged static TableView it's even worse than it sounds IMHO. Apple should give us a way to use static TVs within a ViewController...

Comment: @brainray You can do that actually. Add a table to your view controller in Interface Builder, select it, and navigate to the attributes inspector. The first drop down at the top allows you to change between "Static Cells" and "Dynamic Prototypes"

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of this. However, I'm not sure if this works with multiple sections?

Comment: @brainray it does. By default there is only one, but you can increment this in attributes or copy paste the default sectio.